# How to get version of a package in bower?

Tags: angularjs, bower, angular-routing

I want to install **angular-route**. But before that I want to know it's version. Is there some command in **bower** that shows me a version of the package? These do not show:

```
bower search angular-route   // doesn't show a version

bower version angular-route   // throws an error - bower EINVALIDVERSION
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bower info angular-route //get all package information

bower home angular-route //redirects to bower package homepage
```

For the rest : `bower help`